# Which time stamp format is this 1651928421543667000

Tags: javascript, php, json, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm using an API and it returns timestamp as 1651928421543667000, I can't find the supported format I have tried using

```
strtotime()
datetime() 
strftime()
```

in PHP any help? Thanks!

Comment: That API is maintained by aliens from the future :-p !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a timestamp in nanoseconds. Devs need `ns` precision for some low-level tasks with I/O, RAM, radio signals and etc. You can get the same value in PHP by using a command such as `echo system('date +%s%N');`. You can also convert `ns` into `ms` or `s` by using [basics of metric system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nano-) where `nano` indicates 10^-9.

Comment: or [hrtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hrtime)

Answer (score 0):

So the output is a UNIX-Timestamp format. If you want to convert it to a regular datetime format, use the following code. However, you have to convert it to seconds first by dividing the time by 10^9 as @mardubbles pointed out.

```
$time = time();    
date("d F Y H:i:s", $time);
```

Comment: time()'s unit is in seconds. OP's timestamp is nanoseconds. So a conversion would have to take place first (a division, or a truncation, to get it into seconds) in order for your solution to be viable.

Comment: You are right, my mistake for not realizing that.